# PowerShell - privilege escalation

Tags: windows, privilege-escalation, powershell

In the past, I have used the Sherlock PowerShell script to quickly find missing software patches for local privilege escalation vulnerabilities.

However, I am looking for a similar script, but I struggle to find one. I thought to make one myself rather than looking for such a script.

However, I wanted to first ask the community, if you guys think that Sherlock Powershell is still relevant or there is something better out there or I should go with making my own script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If* I use a script to check for Windows PrivEsc, I usually go with [WinPEAS](https://github.com/carlospolop/PEASS-ng/tree/master/winPEAS) for quite a while with solid success in verious CTF challenges.

I don't know sherlock though ;)